# How to get Native instruments audio 6 to work in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, alsa, soundcard

I have recently reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 after some time of not using any Linux distro and I'm am having issues with the following sound card:

**Native Instruments Audio 6**.

I used to have it working correctly in Ubuntu 12.04 with the .asoundrc file from [here](http://www.native-instruments.com/forum/threads/audio-6-linux-support.136907/).

Now, the sound card is detected *but* the channel configuration seems to be different. I am trying to call in alsa the pcms t6_pair1, t6_pair2 or t6_pair3 and it returns an error. Like if the device doesn’t exist. Also when I use the alsa mixer on the device (hw:2,0) I see the Direct Thru Inputs and Line Ins (mentioned as Outputs...), I can't see the outputs (A, B and Main) and it doesn’t detect any inputs.

Anyone know how i could get this soundcard to work properly again in 14.04?

Comment: must have made a mistake copying the url :  http://www.native-instruments.com/forum/threads/audio-6-linux-support.136907/

Comment: ad a look at the config and it's out of my league...  So I upvoted your question and with the edits it should be clearer to everyone *who does know about this stuff* how to help you... (also: I deleted my comment about 404 so you should as well to keep things uncluttered)

Comment: I made progress with the .asoudrc, it just doesnt load, but it does load from /etc/asound.conf. So i can now acces the pairs i want from aplay.

The poblem is with alsamixer, it just displays the phono and pass through switches (which i can correctly control with amixer) and no volume controls for either input or output. It seems both capture and playback pcms are muted and i cant get them to unmute.

Comment: numid=1,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=6,min=0,max=36,step=0
: values=0,0,0,0,0,0
| | chmap-fixed=FL,FR,FC,LFE,RL,RR
                                                                                                                                        
ximo@ximo-ubuntu:~$ amixer -c T6 cset numid=1 36,36,36,36,36,36
amixer: Control hw:2 element write error: Operation not permitted

Comment: Problem solved... it was just a faulty usb port causing the trouble. Also This card seems to not have any volume controls in alsa mixer.

Comment: Could you please answer your own question (including the details that led you to your answer) It looks like just copying your comments into the answer and then deleting the comments will get you there 80%!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved... it was just a faulty usb port (actually usb 2.0 being dsiabled on bios) causing the trouble.

Using a good usb 2.0 port the soundcard works off the bat, with just the asoundrc file.

This card seems to not have any volume controls in alsa mixer just the channel maps which are fixed and cannot be modified.